# Difference between batch and daemon process

Tags: linux, unix, process, batch-processing, daemon

I am new to UNIX and have this basic confusion between a batch process and a daemon process.

Basically, there are 3 types of process in Unix : interactive, batch and daemon.

I am crystal clear about the interactive process but still very confused about batch and daemon process.

Can anybody please provide the detailed explanation and difference between two?

Answer (score 7):

A daemon process is one that persists in memory, usually in the background, taking action when something in the environment prompts it to. Examples include crond, cupsd, and httpd.

A batch process is one that is invoked in the background from another process (usually a daemon) and performs some processing before exiting. Examples include updatedb, makewhatis, and logrotate.